# Firefox runs in invisible mode when selenium server is started using services

Tags: windows-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-rc

I am running selenium test cases through phpunit on cloud.
So for starting selenium server on cloud I wrote a service which runs the selenium server when i start the cloud server instance from my pc.
The test runs successfully but the browser is not visible, when i see the task manger the browser is running and test cases are also passing.
I tried running the server manually and the firefox is visible.
I am not getting why the firefox is invisible when i run the server through windows service.

Is there any setting i have to turn on as i am executing remotely without logging to any user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what was going wrong.

I created service which starts when instance starts but we have not logged in any of the user available only the services were started. And when i used to log in and see whether the fire fox is started or not i used to see the firefox running in task manager and not on display because i have not started the service by logging in so i was not able to see it.

So i figured out and made the service for auto login and at startup started the required file to execute and now when i run my tests then it starts the firefox browser with the specific login.

When i too login with the same i am not seeing the browser but when i open the task manager and switch the active user with other than i am able to see the Browser correctly.

Thanks to all for giving your valuable time for me.